# Futures - expected (), found struct futures::Map

Tags: rust, serde, hyper

I'm attempting to send a request off with [Hyper](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.13.0-alpha.1/hyper/), then deserialize it via JSON through [Serde](https://serde.rs/), but I cannot seem to wrap my head around futures and I'm receiving type mismatch errors stating `expected (), found struct [put some odd struct here]`. Nor can I wrap my head around the incredibly long and confusing error messages they spit out on each change. Here's my code:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use futures::{
    Future,
    Stream,
    future
};
use hyper::{
    Body,
    Client,
    Response,
    StatusCode,
    Uri,
    client::HttpConnector,
};
use serde::{ Deserialize };
use std::error::{ Error };

enum JsonError
{
    RequestError(hyper::Error),
    ResponseError(StatusCode),
    DeserializeError(serde_json::Error),
}

fn get_json
    <'t, T, F>
    (client: &Client<HttpConnector>, uri: Uri)
-> impl Future<Item = T, Error = JsonError>
where
    T : Deserialize<'t>
{
    let f = client
        .get(uri)
        .map(|response|
        {
            let (parts, body) = response.into_parts();

            if parts.status.is_success()
            {
                body
                    .fold(
                        vec![],
                        |mut accum, chunk|
                        {
                            accum.extend_from_slice(&*chunk);
                            Ok(accum)
                        }
                    )
                    .map(|v|
                    {
                        serde_json::from_slice::<T>(&v)
                            .map_err(|err| JsonError::DeserializeError(err))
                    })
            }

            future::err(JsonError::ResponseError(parts.status))
        })
        .map_err(|err| JsonError::RequestError(err));

    return f;
}
```

I am completely lost and I think any advice could help at this point.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting from this code, and what line it refers to?

Comment: Line 32 gives the error `expected struct 'get_json::futures::Finished', found type parameter`. Lines 44 to 57 give the error `expected (), found struct 'get_json::futures::Map'`.

Comment: Can you paste the full error messages in the question? This would make it easier to see which is line 32 and which are lines 44 to 57, and would allow us to see which part of the line the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: Do you know that you use the old `Future` API? If you can, you should use the `async`/`.await` notation, that makes the code really easier to read. See: https://seanmonstar.com/post/187493499882/hyper-alpha-supports-asyncawait

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple errors stemming from logic issues when chaining futures. I have fixed its implementation, and it is [**available on the playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d6c90c15a799446470ef89e6b68fbe46) but I would strongly recommend you walk with me through what I changed.

But first, a recurring trend in your code:

## #1: `Future::map()`'s return type

`Future::map()` allows you to change a future result of type `T` into type `R`, and it does so with the assumption that the *transformation cannot fail* (i.e. `Fn(T) -> R`). You've used `map()` multiple times in your code while returning either another `Future`, or a `Result`. Both are incorrect.

For `Future` chaining, `and_then()` allows you to perform the mapping `fn(T) -> IntoFuture<Item = R>` with error types remaining the same

For `Result`, convert them via `future::result()` into an already-executed future so you can also `and_then()`

## #2: Errors

Errors do not convert themselves, especially not if you do not define their conversion methods. For this purpose, I've implemented `From<hyper::Error>` for your error type:

```
impl From<hyper::Error> for JsonError {
    fn from(s: hyper::Error) -> JsonError {
        JsonError::RequestError(s)
    }
}
```

This allows you to use `into()` wherever the typechecker notices that it is possible to do so.

Do note, however, that because of `hyper`'s own response type, `err_into()` gets the type checker confused, hence the explicit `map(|r| r.into())`.

## #3: `Deserialize` and lifetimes

`Deserialize<'t>` is not the exact trait you were looking for. This trait implies that the **entire object** needs to live for lifetime `'t`. In a non-futures world, this would probably pass, but not in this case where the return object needs to be owned (hence the lifetime error you are getting).

`for<'t> Deserialize<'t>` is a completely different beast, and tells the compiler that this trait will have a lifetime `'t`, but will then be an owned object, or in other words, that the slice used to create the object will need to live for lifetime `'t`, not the entire returned object. Just what we need!

An additional nitpick: you really ought to separate the response parsing from the HTTP extraction in this function. As it stands right now, if I make a request over HTTPS, I will not be able to use your `get_json()` function, as my connector for `hyper` would then be `TlsConnector<HttpConnector>`. Problematic ;-)

---

The code:

```
use futures::{future, Future, Stream};
use hyper::{client::HttpConnector, Client, StatusCode, Uri};
use serde::Deserialize;

enum JsonError {
    RequestError(hyper::Error),
    ResponseError(StatusCode),
    DeserializeError(serde_json::Error),
}

impl From<hyper::Error> for JsonError {
    fn from(s: hyper::Error) -> JsonError {
        JsonError::RequestError(s)
    }
}

fn get_json<T, F>(
    client: &Client<HttpConnector>,
    uri: Uri,
) -> impl Future<Item = T, Error = JsonError>
where
    T: for<'t> Deserialize<'t> + 'static,
{
    client.get(uri).map_err(|e| e.into()).and_then(
        |response| -> Box<dyn Future<Item = T, Error = JsonError>> {
            let (parts, body) = response.into_parts();

            match parts.status.is_success() {
                true => Box::new(body
                    .map_err(|e| e.into())
                    .fold(
                        vec![],
                        |mut accum, chunk| -> Box<dyn Future<Item = Vec<u8>, Error = JsonError>>
                        {
                            accum.extend_from_slice(&*chunk);
                            Box::new(future::ok(accum))
                        }
                    )
                    .and_then(|v|
                    {
                        future::result(serde_json::from_slice::<T>(&v))
                            .map_err(|err| JsonError::DeserializeError(err))
                    })),
                false => Box::new(future::err(JsonError::ResponseError(parts.status)))
            }
        },
    )
}
```

Comment: I usually use [`serde::de::DeserializeOwned`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.101/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html) instead which is an alias for `for<'de> Deserialize<'de>`

Comment: First off, thank you so much! I'd spent about 8 hours at that point trying to figure where to even begin solving my questions and I wasn't thinking straight. Your response has cleared up a ton that multiple tutorials didn't seem to get through my head. Second, I've never seen `for<'lifetime>` syntax before - is that relatively new?

Comment: Also, I knew about the connector problem, but was leaving that for after I solved the future bugs. Would it be enough to make it `&Client<C, B>` with the appropriate traits and lifetimes, or would this still be too restrictive? Seems to me you could use any client then.